# mv : cannot stat, no such file or directory

Tags: bash

`mv` command is unable to find the file that I'm trying to rename. 
I've looked to solutions involving double quotes, directory expansion and variable evaluation but nothing explains why this Bash script won't work.

I've also confirmed that the path is correct and the file exists. If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Below is the code in question with an explanation:

```
BASEPATH="/media/matt/DATA/Flow_Processing/fvv/rafa_1_ifsc/STEA_flow/"

FRSTFRM=00030
LSTFRM=00270

FRSTCAM=001
LSTCAM=012

for cam in $(eval echo "{$FRSTCAM..$LSTCAM}")
do
 for frame in $(eval echo "{$FRSTFRM..$LSTFRM}")
 do

  SRC="${BASEPATH}${cam}/flow/FVV_0_${cam}_${frame}_flow.flo"
  DST="${BASEPATH}${cam}/flow/FVV_2_${cam}_$frame.flo"

  mv -f $SRC $DST

 done
done
```

So essentially I'm trying to iterate through a file system structure using `$cam` and `$frame` variables which are padded strings.

I'm trying to change the filenames in each of these folders from:

```
FVV_0_<cam num>_<frame num>_flow.flo
```

to

```
FVV_2_<cam num>_<frame num>.flo
```

e.g. for camera 1 and frame 1 the file changes from:

```
FVV_0_001_00001_flow.flo
```

to

```
FVV_2_001_00001.flo
```

I've printed `$SRC` and `$DST` and they output the exact path that I expect. The problem is that in spite of this, `mv` produces this error:

```
"cannot stat: <file> : no such file or directory"
```

e.g.

**SRC:**

`/media/matt/DATA/Flow_Processing/fvv/rafa_1_ifsc/STEA_flow/005/flow/FVV_0_005_00190_flow.flo`

**DST:**
     `/media/matt/DATA/Flow_Processing/fvv/rafa_1_ifsc/STEA_flow/005/flow/FVV_2_005_00190.flo`

`mv` error:

```
mv: cannot stat '/media/matt/DATA/Flow_Processing/fvv/rafa_1_ifsc/STEA_flow/005/flow/FVV_0_005_00190_flow.flo': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you try to print the `SRC` and `DST` variables before `mv` command?

Comment: Hi, yeah I've done a print and the file name matches the path perfectly. 
For example if the path is :
/media/matt/DATA/Flow_Processing/fvv/rafa_1_ifsc/STEA_flow/001/flow/FVV_0_001_00033_flow.flo

then echo $SRC outputs exactly that. But yet I still have the problem that mv cannot perform the action

Comment: Alright. Kindly update those paths in your question along with the error. Kindly confirm that if it's not a `sudo` issue. Did you try to run the script under `sudo`? How are you executing this?

Comment: hey, I added the sample output. 
It's not a sudo error. I've checked the file permissions and ran with sudo just in case with the same result

Comment: That's good. Can you add `ls -al $SRC` and `ls -al $DST` before `mv`?

Comment: What happens if you try to rename one specific file (by hardcoding values)? Same error? Are you sure that the variables 100% respond to the real files? I've seen many cases where the culprit was just one different character or such :)

Comment: @Azeem adding ls -al prints "ls : cannot access" but I expect this is due to running ls on a file as opposed to a directory?

Comment: @PesaThe It actually works fine when I run it hardcoded on the command line! That's the weirdest part :) I've been peering over the syntax and spelling for the past hour and can confirm it's not a silly character (been there before though).

Comment: @MattMoynininhan: It doesn't matter. It should list the files too. You need to verify the paths. That's the error. :)

Comment: @Azeem you're right, it should. ls -al works if I copy the path to the command line and run it. Again though, it's the exact same path that gets output from the script. 
Is there any way that there's a screw up with literal string interpretations?

Comment: @MattMoynininhan: Can you test this script with a simple path? OR try to put that hardcoded paths to SRC and DST and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by fixing an error in write permissions with mounted media. 
My `/etc/fstab` file required me to add `"vers=1.0"` at the end of the mount options for my NAS media drive.

Thanks to the help from [@Azeem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7670262/azeem) who helped me realize that I hadn't got permission to access files on the drive.

Comment: That's great, Matt! Cheers! :) And, you are welcome! :)